Remove packages that do not exist anymore and can be edited in Pip
I install a local package in editable mode.
pip install -e ~/subdir/test_example
Then, I switch branches to a branch where subdir/test_example/pyproject.toml does not exist yet.
git switch master
Now Pip is in a broken state:
$ pip freeze
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "<my_venv>\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\vcs\git.py", line 501, in get_repository_root
    r = cls.run_command(
  File "<my_venv>\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\vcs\versioncontrol.py", line 650, in run_command
    return call_subprocess(
  File "<my_venv>\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\utils\subprocess.py", line 141, in call_subprocess
    proc = subprocess.Popen(
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
NotADirectoryError: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid

I can manually remove the editable install and fix Pip: pip uninstall test_example, after which pip freeze and other commands are fine.
The obvious solution here is "ensure your python packages exist across all branches of a repo", but that may not be an option.
Is there a way to remove all broken links to editable packages?

if there's a tag for pip -e editable packages, I wasn't able to find it.

"Is there a way to remove all broken links to editable packages?" No, not an easy and straightforward way that I know of. -- You would need to write code for this.
